# how to create a facebook app that sends invitations to friends, but they do not see the invitation unless

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

The application should make possible for users to choose a certain friend or friends from his friends list by checking a small box next to their friends profile picture and name, and to send them invitations. However, their friends (those to whom the invitations were sent) wouldn't be able to see any notification or invitation (no action whatsoever) unless they are also using this application, and they have also sent the same invitation to the user. So, a user sends notifications to chosen friends, no one sees anything unless those who have received invitations have also sent invitations to the user. When both persons send an invitation, they receive a notification from the app, and they are notified that the match has happened. I wonder if this is even possible and if it is, how do i do it?

Comment: Please tell what have you tried to make this work.

Comment: well, nothing yet, since i have no idea on how to do it or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. But you will have to build it yourself; there is no built-in functionality for this. The logic is very simple though: You need to store these "invitations" in a database, and when someone invites another person who has previously invited them, you can send them both a notification via the [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/notifications-api/).

Comment: Using the notifications api is a great idea - but you really should mention that **it is still in beta** and is prone to changes in the future... I also wouldn't recommend using it in production... Building a POC would be a good idea so that you'll be ready when the API comes out of beta and becomes a stable part of the API.

Comment: There are also some other considerations like the fact that it  currently **only** works for applications on facebook.com.

Answer (score 0):

So this is definitely possible but it will require that you take some steps to ensure the invitation [friend selector](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) only displays relevant users. You'll also need to implement your own type of "tracking" for the invites to enforce the logic you need.

#### Initial invite logic -

When initializing the invitation dialog for the first time, you specify filters to display only certain users. One of these filters is called `app_users`. When using this filter, only friends with the application installed will be shown.  This request will always contain a notification, there is no way for you to prevent this as it is in the core of the requests functionality...

After this request is sent you'll have to save in your database a record of what users sent invitations to others (you'll need this for the subsequent calls to the dialog).

---

At this stage, a user has sent X requests to other users (who have the app installed) and you have records of exactly who was invited.

---

#### Subsequent invite logic -

When one of the users (who was previously sent an invite) now wants to send requests to others (by your logic only users who have already sent requests to him), you can use another filter to limit the users displayed in the dialog... You can specify a filter in the following form (example taken from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)-

```
[{name: 'Friends who have already sent me an invite', user_ids: [1, 2, 3]}]
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the filters option is disabled on mobile dialogs and will not affect the set of users that appear in the dialog.